# How to capitalize words in <title> tag

Tags: php

How can I capitalize words in `<title>` tag?

I am currently using this, when the url is page.php?=title.  This php shows me the title but I need it to be capitalized.

```
<title>
    <?php 
        $page = $_GET['page']; 
        echo $page;
        // 'page'
    ?>
</title>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `ucwords` function:

```
<title><?php echo ucwords($page); ?></title>
```

Comment: @ShyqyriZeqiri Don't forget to accept the correct answer by clicking on the correct sign beside it.

Answer (score 2):

`ucfirst()` and `ucwords()` exists, but will only work on ISO-8859 encodings.

For UTF-8 and other encodings, use `mb_convert_case()`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo strtoupper ($page);
```

or for the first letter to be capital:

```
echo ucfirst ($page);
```

Comment: do you want each word capital

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want 'Page', if so this is what you're looking for. Later you might want to add both what data you've got now, and what (exactly) it is you want to end up with :)

```
<title><?php $page= $_GET['page']; echo htmlspecialchars(ucfirst($page)); ?></title>
```

If you do not need the $page variable later on in the file, I would change the title tag to something like this

```
<title><?php echo !empty($_GET['page']) ? htmlspecialchars(ucfirst($page)) : 'Unnamed' ; ?></title>
```